# how to display .txt file contents to the browser using python

Tags: python

We have a `test.py` that should display a `.png` file and `.txt` file in same browser. Below is my code:

```
print "Content-type: image/png\n"
print file(r"/var/www/cgi-bin/testpie.png", "rb").read()
myurl = "file://var/www/html/test.txt"

webbrowser.open(myurl)
```

But I am getting only `.png` file in the browser. So how can I display both in browser using python?

Comment: It is unusual to directly use `file()`: it is recommended instead to use `open()`, which is the standard way of opening a file. Furthermore, you do not need to use a raw string with your path, since it does not contained any escaped (`\`) character.

Comment: Your code is confusing two things. `webbrowser.open()` is for opening a URL in a web browser on the same machine the script is running on. If you use this in a CGI/WSGI script, it won't affect the web browser that connected as a client; it will open a browser on the _server_.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers display HTML documents. HTML documents can contain text in a `div`, `span`, `p`, etc. tag, just by including the text inside the element. For example, `<div>Hello!</div>` displays the text `Hello`. But they don't contain images directly; instead, they include *links* to images, as the `src` of an `img` tag. For example, `<img src="http://example.com/foo.png">` displays the foo.png image.

So, there are two ways to do what you want.

---

The easy way is to expose *two* resources (with separate URLs): (1) the PNG image, and (2) an HTML page that contains a link to the PNG image (and contains the text directly).

For example…

testpie_image.py:

```
print "Content-type: image/png\n"
print open(r"/var/www/cgi-bin/testpie.png", "rb").read()
```

testpie.py:

```
print """Content-type: text/html

<html><head></head><body>
<img src="testpie_image.py" />
<div>{}</div>
</body></html>
""".format(open(r"/var/www/html/test.txt").read())
```

Now, if someone browses to `http://example.com/cgi-bin/testpie.py`, that will trigger your second script, so they will get an HTML page like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<img src="testpie_image.py" />
<div>Blah blah this is my text file.</div>
</body></html>
```

Their browser will then follow that link to `http://example.com/cgi-bin/testpie-image.py`, which will trigger your first script, so they will get the PNG image.

---

The harder way is to use a special kind of URL scheme called [`data:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which lets you embed data in-line as if it were a link to a separate resource. You have to do a bit more work to embed it, but it means you only need one URL instead of two:

```
print """Content-type: text/html

<html><head></head><body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}"</img>
<div>{}</div>
</body></html>
""".format(open(r"/var/www/cgi-bin/testpie.png", "rb").read().encode("base64"),
           open(r"/var/www/html/test.txt").read())
```

Now, when someone browses to `http://example.com/cgi-bin/testpie.py`, they'll get an HTML page like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,1Ab…
Z2y" />
<div>Blah blah this is my text file.</div>
</body></html>
```

---

> Hi, I am excuting a python file from html file, when i enter some keywords in text box and click submit, then it will excute the python file. so the python file generate two files 1) .png and 2) text file. so my requirement is to display .png and .txt file in web browser immediately when i click submit in the html.

OK, let me explain.

I'll assume you're using a traditional form submit connected to a traditional CGI server. When you click the submit button in your web browser, this sends a request to the CGI script that builds the HTML document. That document contains the text file, and also contains an image linked to a second CGI script. Your web browser automatically loads the image by following the link to the second CGI, which generates and returns the PNG file, which gets displayed. So, you see the image and the text in one browser page.

---

One last thing: You probably don't want to put the text file inside your /var/www hierarchy, and if you're using a `data:` URL you probably don't want to put the image file there either.

Comment: Hi, we need to display text file contents and png image in same browser at a time using python.

Comment: @VittalCherala: I assumed you already knew how to print a text file. I've edited the answer to show that as well.

Comment: Hi, I am excuting a python file from html file, when i enter some keywords in text box and click submit, then it will excute the python file. so the python file generate two files 1) .png and 2) text file. so my requirement is to display .png and .txt file in web browser immediately when i click submit in the html.

Comment: @VittalCherala: See the new update. Also, please try it out and, if it doesn't do what you want, explain exactly what you want to be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display two types of data then you need to either:

- Have two separate HTTP requests
- Use data formats where one can be embedded in the other (e.g. HTML instead of text, with the PNG embedded as a URI with the `data:` scheme).

You can't return a text document and a PNG image at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple HTML file using Python containing both the content of the text and the image and open this file in the browser.